# Matrix representation of linear map - returns a non-square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be the real vector space $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x+y+z=0\}$. Consider the basis for $V$ given by $B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Conside the linear map $\psi:V\rightarrow V$ defined by $\psi(x,y,z)=(z,y,x)$.

Find the matrix representation $M_B(\psi)$ of $\psi$.

I thought a matrix representation would be the matrix with rows as the effect of the linear map on the columns of the basis? Then we would have $M_B(\psi)=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&1\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$. But the next part of the question asks for eigenvalues which cannot exist as $M$ is not a square matrix. Can anybody help?

Comment: Note that you're mapping two vectors to two other vectors in the same space. This means the matrix should be $2 \times 2$. In general if $V$ has dimension $n$ then any linear map $V \rightarrow V$ will have an $n \times n$ matrix representation regardless of what basis you use.

Answer (score 4):

What thought about matrix representations is incorrect. Here is how you would go about finding the entries of the $2 \times 2$ matrix of $\psi$ relative to the basis $B$. Let $v_1,v_2$ denote the elements of $B$. We find that
$$
\psi(v_1) = \pmatrix{0\\1\\-1} = 0 \cdot v_1 + 1 \cdot v_2.
$$
Correspondingly, the first column of $M_B(\psi)$ is given by $(0,1)$. That is, we have
$$
M_{B}(\psi) = \pmatrix{0&?\\1&?}.
$$
The second column of $M_B(\psi)$ can be found be expressing $\psi(v_2)$ as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. We find that $\psi(v_2) = (-1)\cdot v_1 + (-1)\cdot v_2$, so that the second column of $M_B(\psi)$ is $(-1,-1)$. Putting all that together, we find that the matrix is given by
$$
M_B(\psi) = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&-1}.
$$

Comment: What happens to the third entry of the matrix representation? As in, does the $-1$ have no effect?

Comment: @turkey131 I don't understand why you believe that there should be a "third entry", nor do I understand what you mean by the "effect" of the $-1$.

Comment: @turkey131 Perhaps you believe that the way we produced this first column is by computing $\psi(v_1)$ and only taking the first two entries. That is **not** what's going on here. I suggest that you take a minute to try to understand the explanatory text.

Comment: @turkey131 Note that
$$
\psi(v_2) = \pmatrix{-1\\0\\1}.
$$
The corresponding column of $M_B(\psi)$ (i.e. the coordinates of this output relative to the basis $B$) is $(-1,-1)$. Note that we did **not** simply use the first two entries of the result.